# Mutiple tag change within Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, tags

```
this is my json data
[
{
    "menu":
    {
        "MenuID":"1",
        "OmfID":"1",
        "menu_name":"Coyote Blues Louisiana Menu",
        "menu_description":"Full Menu served all day long. ",
        "menu_note":null,
        "currency_symbol":"$$",
        "language":"En",
        "disabled":"0",
        "menu_uid":"Lake Charles\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
        "menu_duration_name":"All Day",
        "menu_duration_time_start":"11:00:00",
        "menu_duration_time_end":"11:00:00",
        "fDateAdded":"2013-12-20 13:00:44"
    }
}
]
```

this is my javascript

```
function Menus_RestaurantID()
{
    var query = $.getJSON('Menus/RestaurantID.json',function(data)
    {
        console.log("success");
    });
    query.error(function (data)
    {
        alert("error");
    });
    query.complete(function(data)
    {
        var h=new String();
        var text = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
        //alert("data length equals ");
        //alert(text.length);
        var t=new String();
        t+='<ul class="tabs">';
        /*for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
        {
            t+='<li><a href="#">'+text[i]['menu'].menu_name+'</a></li>';
        }
        t+='</ul>';

        h+='<div class="panes">';*/
        for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++)
        {
                h+='<div>';

                //h+=text[i]['menu'].MenuID+'<br>';
                //h+=text[i]['menu'].OmfID+'<br>';
                //h+=text[i]['menu'].menu_name+'<br>';
                if(text[i]['menu'].menu_description!=null)
                    h+=text[i]['menu'].menu_description+'<br>';
                if(text[i]['menu'].menu_note!=null)
                    h+=text[i]['menu'].menu_note+'<br>';                    
                h+=text[i]['menu'].currency_symbol+'<br>';
                h+=text[i]['menu'].language+'<br>';
                //if(text[i]['menu'].disabled!=null)
                    //h+=text[i]['menu'].disabled+'<br>';

                h+=text[i]['menu'].menu_uid+'<br>';
                h+=text[i]['menu'].menu_duration_name+'<br>';
                h+=text[i]['menu'].menu_duration_time_start+'<br>';
                h+=text[i]['menu'].menu_duration_time_end+'<br><br><br><br>';
                //h+=text[i]['menu'].fDateAdded+'';

                h +='</div>';
        }
        h += '</div>';
        //alert("h");
        //alert(h); 

        $('#menus').append(t);  
        $('#menus').append(h);  
    });
    $(function() 
    {
        // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
        $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
    });
```

I'm retrieving the data right but I want to display the information in tab dividers. Like in http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.htm but as of right now the only thing it does is shows all the data in just one. I'm not sure if its because of how im retrieving the data or what.

My Question is:

1. Why isn't my code displaying properly?
2. What is another way to display the data in tabs?

Comment: You should be using the `.done()` and `.fail()` methods. Also `var t = '';` is equivalent to `var t = new String();`.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the question i asked
Im specifically worrying about the tags right now

Comment: im not using an object literal. Im using the parsedJSON(text) which returns all my data into arrays which have a length.

Answer (score 0):

The following line sets up the tabs:

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
```

However, that is run when the page loads.  At that point your tabs do not exist in the page.  You add them later via the ajax request.  You need to add that line to the complete callback after you have added the tabs to the page.

Edit:

Bunch of problems here

1. Your tabs `ul`is empty since the code that fills it is commented out
2. You have no connection between the list items (which I guess are meant for the tab header) and the divs containing the tab content (the divs should have an id and the links in the list items should target that id)
3. You need to call `.tabs()` on the container containing both the headings and the content, not just the headings
4. You should be calling `.done()` not `.complete()`
5. You had called `$.getJSON` so the data returned will be parsed JSON already but you try to parse it again.

I think you might want something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf2y4/).  (I have changed to hard-code the `var data` in the `.done()` to make it work in the fiddle.  In a real use case remove the `var data = ...` defintion and set data as a paramater to the callback like `query.done(function(data){` )

I suggest also re-reading the [tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and using a debugger to see what is sent back and forth when you make ajax requests and what error messages come in the console (my personal preference is for [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) but Chrome dev tools and fiddler are also options)

Comment: i've tried adding that line of code in various places around where i append the strings to the page and still end up getting nothing

Comment: Your code as posted is missing a close to the  Menus_RestaurantID function and is creating a document ready inside that function which is not advised.

Comment: the code is missing a close from when i copied it over i missed copying it.
What is advised for the problem then?